# Do these sentences have different meaning?

Tags: grammar, past-tense, past-perfect

> - Reading the exercise I knew the answer
> - Reading the exercise I had known the answer
> - Reading the exercise I came to know the answer

I am confused with these sentences. What's the difference between them?

Comment: I can't imagine any context in which #2 would be idiomatic. #1 is potentially ambiguous, per [an earlier comment of mine](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/302169/repetitive-pronoun#comment564404_302169) about "fronted" continuous participle adverbial clauses. On the basis of "default syntactic interpretation", #1 should mean *I [already] knew the answer **at the same time as** I read the exercise* (we only arrive at the *intended* meaning using "common sense"). That potentially ambiguity doesn't exist with #3, and could be avoided in #1 with an initial preposition (***On, After***,...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sentences 1 and 3 are both grammatical, although they have somewhat different meanings. Sentence 1 does not indicate when you learned the answer, while sentence 3 indicates that you learned ("came to know") it while you were reading the exercise.

Sentence 2 uses the past perfect tense ("had known"), which is generally reserved for indicating an action that occurred before another action in the past. Because the phrase "reading the exercise" does not have any tense markers, we do now know whether it happened in the past; I would therefore avoid using the past perfect tense in this sentence.

Finally, I'll point out that most writers would probably include a comma after "reading the exercise", although it is not required.